# How to filter bootstrap cards based on search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

I created an app using Laravel 5.8. Please scroll down to see the images before you continue to read, that will help as I explain the issue.

The search box is intended to look for matching text within `<H5>` tags, an then hide any `recipe-card` ID divs.

**There are two issues:**

1. The divs do not collapse when I search.
2. Some elements, like the card footer with the hash tags get removed as well. This is not intended.

I'm hoping someone could help me out with the JavaScript I need to use to accomplish this.

- Search titles (H5 tags)
- Hide any recipe cards that don't have the search criteria.

> Laravel view.blade.php to show my recipe cards

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row pb-4">
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" class="filterinput form-control" placeholder="Search recipe titles and tags...">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @foreach ($recipes as $recipe)
    <div class="col-lg-4 pb-4" id="recipe-card">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <a href="/recipes/{{ $recipe->id}}"><img class="card-img-top " src="{{ $recipe->imgurl}}" alt="{{ $recipe->name }}"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="/recipes/{{ $recipe->id}}"> {{ $recipe->name }} </a> {{ $recipe->favourite == 'Yes' ? ' Fav' : '' }} </h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <span id="">Time:{{ $recipe->totaltime }}</span>
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <span id="">Type:{{ $recipe->mealtype }}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted text-truncate">
                <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $recipe->tags }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach

</div>
```

> Here is the JavaScript that I currently use to filter:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchbox").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#recipe-card div").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).find('h5').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The above code produces this:

> **Before using search**

[image]

> **After searching for recipes with titles (H5 tags) of "bowl"**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector `#recipe-card div` isn't actually doing what you want it to do. Instead of grabbing the first div inside the card, it's grabbing **all** divs inside the card.

Additionally, you should avoid re-using the same ID for multiple cards and instead use something like a data-role. IDs are supposed to be unique, so having multiple of the same IDs is generally bad practice.

If you instead used something like `data-role="recipe"`, you could use this selector:

```
$('div[data-role="recipe"] div:first)
```

OR, simply place a data-role on your inner div and simply select that element specifically.

This might not solve all of your issues, but start with this and let me know if anything remains.

**The below JS solution was appended by OP and this marked as the right answer:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchbox").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('div[data-role="recipe"]').filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).find('h5').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The columns shouldn't all have the same id. Also, the jQuery code should hide the column (col-lg-4), instead of the card. There are a lot of different ways this could be handled in jQuery...

```
$('#searchbox').keyup(function (){
    $('.col-lg-4').removeClass('d-none');
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if (filter && filter.length>0){
        $('.row').find('.col-lg-4 .card-body h5:not(:contains("'+filter+'"))').parentsUntil('.col-lg-4').parent().addClass('d-none');
    }
});
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/IWKdFu4xIJ

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but this solution might need some tweaking. I have been playing with your codeply and forked my own version but there are still problems. When I remove search criteria, the cards don't come back. It also doesn't seem to match on the words well. I'm wondering if you could help make it work nicer? https://www.codeply.com/go/8778Xl0h7g is what I've been trying.

Comment: That's a separate issue. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#searchbox').on("keyup", function() {
        $('.card').show();
        var filter = $(this).val(); 
        $('#recipe-card').find(".card-title:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().css('display','none');
    });
```

If you want the cards to collapse into the right place after filtering, you might consider using bootstrap's "card-columns" or "card-deck" classes for layout.